# How to retrieve 10 record per page rather whole data records using yajra laravel datatable

Tags: php, laravel

I have huge `records` stored in `database`  which is taking `time` to load (sometime more than a **minute**).

so i thought about using `yajra laravel datatable` (https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

**Question:** only 10 `records` has to come from `database` on click of next button next 10 record has to come.

here is my files:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('datatable', ['uses'=>'PostController@datatable']);
Route::get('datatable/getposts', ['as'=>'datatable.getposts','uses'=>'PostController@getPosts']);
```

controller => **PostController.php**

```
public function datatable()
{
    return view('datatable');
}
public function getPosts()
{
    $users = DB::table('data')->select('*');   
    return Datatables::of($users)->make(true);
```

}

view => **datatable.blade.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#users').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.getposts') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'username', name: 'username'},
            {data: 'about', name: 'about'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'}
        ]
    });
}); 
</script>
```

please help me thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: $users = DB::table('data')->select('*')->paginate(10) 

it will gives you data for pagination too.

Comment: @AshishPatel, i have tried that but `datatable` giving some error like this `DataTables warning: table id=users - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7`

Comment: @AshishPatel, without pagination working fine but taking too much time to load!

Comment: why don't you create your own pagination?

Comment: @linktoahref, it is working but next record is not coming?  do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#users').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 20,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.getposts') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'username', name: 'username'},
            {data: 'about', name: 'about'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'}
        ]
    });
}); 
</script>
```

try this